# Listen to My Location icon tap event in Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, listener

For the new Maps API, I noticed that neither [`onMapClick()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener) nor [`onMarkerClick()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) fires when you press the My Location pin on the map.

This suggests to me that there should be a listener somewhere that listens to these event where the My Location touch events are pressed, but I can't find any. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I have been thinking about a workaround like this:

Disable the standard `MyLocation` icon and to create an ordinary marker that functions like the My Location pin.

```
myLocationPin = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .title("My Location")
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mylocation)));
```

And implementing `LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener`:

```
public void onLocationChanged (Location location) {
    myLocationPin.position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)); 
}
```

But I have two problems with this approach:

1. I don't know how to turn the marker off
2. I don't know whether implementing my own `onLocationListener` will break any standard functionality if I replace the default `LocationSource`. Can't find any docs or source code on it.

Comment: You could also use a `GroundOverlay` if you do not want the extra marker functionality, and use the `onMapClick()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was posted, `OnMyLocationChangeListener` was added to the API, making the implementation of a workaround (a lot) easier (i.e. there's no need for a custom `LocationSource` anymore).

So you can draw a `Marker` (with a similar icon) on top of My Location dot in order to receive the corresponding `onMarkerClick()` callback.

```
public class DemoMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMyLocationChangeListener, OnMarkerClickListener { 

    // Note that 'mMap' may be null if the Google Play services APK is not available. 
    private GoogleMap mMap; 
    private Marker myLocationMarker;
    private static BitmapDescriptor markerIconBitmapDescriptor;
    /* ... */

    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(); // Get a reference to the map      
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // Enable the my-location layer 
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this); 
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() { 
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map. 
        if (mMap == null) { 
            mMap = getMap(); 
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map. 
            if (mMap != null) { 
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map:

                // Load custom marker icon
                markerIconBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_location_dot_icon); 

                // When the map is first loaded we need to add our marker on top of My Location dot
                myLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
                        .position(new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude())) 
                        .icon(markerIconBitmapDescriptor)); 

                // Set default zoom 
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f)); 
            } 
        } 
    }   

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        // Remove the old marker object
        myLocationMarker.remove(); 

        // Add a new marker object at the new (My Location dot) location
        myLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
                .position(new LatLng(location().getLatitude(),location().getLongitude())) 
                .icon(markerIconBitmapDescriptor)); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(myLocationMarker)) {
            /* My Location dot callback ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean by "break anything"? can you detail it?

One alternative, you can also try to listen to location change from system location service. request location service in your activity:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locatoinManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,2f,this);
```

your activity extend LocationListener

```
public void onLocationChange(Location location){
     yourLocationPin.position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)); 
}
```

Comment: Well, the `GoogleMap` has a default `LocationSource` which might have functionality that I may lose if I replace it with my own one. I don't know how to override it since there's no way to find out what class it is, and `GoogleMap` has no `getLocationSource()` method.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Seems no straightforward way to get default location source. BUT, if I am not wrong, your target is to catch a touch event on your location marker. As long as you can hold a reference to your marker, your problem sort out. I do not see any disadvantage of using system location service(or implementing your own location source).